# How to sort list of dictionaries by value without using built in functions via Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I wish to sort below list of dictionaries by age key into ascending order without using any built in functions.

```
[{'Name': 'Alpha', 'Age': 14}, {'Name': 'Bravo', 'Age': 21}, {'Name': 'Charlie', 'Age': 12}]
```

I wish to have below output.

```
[{'Name': 'Charlie', 'Age': 12}, {'Name': 'Alpha', 'Age': 14}, {'Name': 'Bravo', 'Age': 21}]
```

I have done it via sorted function but unable to find a way to do it without same. I believe this should be done via bubble sort method but am unable to implement it.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is already answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary....Also you can use :```sorted(listname, key=lambda k : k['Age']) ```

Comment: I do not wish to use sorted function as mentioned above. Need not to use built in functions.